# junk after document element Firefox Error Loading Content With JQuery Get

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I have a page (which is unfortunately behind a login system), which basically has a nav bar down the left of a list of articles, and when you click on an article, it loads the content from a .inc file stored on the server, using a provided file path.

This works fine on Google Chrome.

However, on Firefox, when the page loads, I get this weird javascript error:

"junk after document element" - When I click the error, it takes me to line 2 of the content from the first article being loaded.

Let me show you some code.

This is the last JS function which is run when the page has finished loading, and it's purpose is to load the initial article.

```
function initialise_family_center_page() 
{
    if (current_element_id == "" || current_element_id == "family_center_general_info") //If this is the first article to be loaded
    {
        //Get the file path of the inc file to load

        var content_directory = file path....;

        jQuery.get(content_directory, function(data) 
        {
            $('#family_center_main_content').html(data);    //Load the content
        }); 
    }   
}
```

The content in the .inc file being loaded is as follows:

```
<p>Some text</p>

<p>Some text</p>
```

It's worth mentioning at this point, that in Chrome and Firefox, the content loads. However in firefox, because of the JS error, you can no longer use the rest of the page because the JS has stopped working.

Interesting point, which I discovered from googling the problem, is if I change the content of the file to:

```
<html>
    <p>Some Text</p>

    <p>Some Text</p>
</html>
```

Then the error does not appear and the page works (until you load the next content file without the  tags.

However, this is not a suitable fix because there are thousands and thousands of files.

Can anyone help?

Comment: `html` tag is [optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags). Are you sure you don't have any white space before first `<p>` or after last one? Same issue changing extension file to `.html`? And maybe try passing datatype to `$.get()` method: `jQuery.get(content_directory, function(data) {...}, 'html');`

Comment: Hi @A.Wolff Thanks for your help. There is no white space. Passing the datatype to the function didn't work either. But changing the extension to .html got rid of the error. Unfortunately, that's not an option. The files are external and must stay as they are.

Comment: I'd try then: `$('#family_center_main_content').html($.parseHTML(data));`. I'm not sure if your issue comes from parsing string or what... And instead of `$.get()`, i'd use `$('#family_center_main_content').load(content_directory);`

Comment: Nope sorry :( I can't even work out what the error message means or what it's trying to tell me.

Comment: If you replace: `$('#family_center_main_content').html(data);` with just `console.log(data);` have you gt still error message? BTW, what output `console.log(data);`? Same as `console.log(data.trim());`?  I'm sorry, i'm not FF user and never encountered this kind of issue

Comment: Both the data and the data.trim() are the same, and the error still appears with just the console.log. Sorry - I usually use chrome so I'm not used to firefox being so picky!

Comment: So at least we (I) know now that problem is not regarding parsing data. You should check headers request in FF and maybe compare them to the ones you get on chrome. A `.inc` file i suppose should be handled like a txt file but who knows... Now i'm wondering if setting dataType for `$.get()` to `text` has any effect?!

Comment: data type text didn't work, but looking at the headers, chrome has status code: 200 OK in the header for requesting the file, but firefox has 304 not modified. Although apparently that's a caching thing. Interestingly. Chrome says content length is 766 but firefox says 768...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same problem. I had created a base page where clicking on a `nav` element triggered an `$.ajax()` fetch of an `inc` file that would populate the main `div` on the page - as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  // Set trigger and container variables
  var trigger = $('nav.primary ul li a'),
      container = $('#se-main');
  trigger.on('click', function(){
    // Set click target from data attribute
    target = this.target;
    $.ajax({
        url:'../inc/'+target + '.inc',
        success: function(data){
            // Load target page into container
            container.html(data);
        },
        dataType: "text" // this seems to be ignored in Firefox
    });
// snip other stuff
});
```

The Firefox console always logged the 'junk after document element' error unless I edited the INC files and wrapped the text in `<html></html>`. (The page content still updated, though - so the user wasn't held up by it).

To fix this: add `inc` to the `text/html` line in the apache **mime.types** config file.

Find the line with

```
text/html                   html htm
```

change to

```
text/html                   html htm inc
```

Then restart apache.

That worked for me.

Default file locations:

**Linux**: `/etc/mime.types`;

**WAMP**: `[wampdir]\bin\apache\[apacheversion]\conf\mime.types`

**XAMPP**: `[xamppdir]\apache\conf\mime.types`

Where [wampdir] is wherever you installed WAMP/XAMPP, and [apacheversion] is the version of apache that WAMP is using.

This solution is no use if you don't have access to the **mime.types** file, or if you're running on shared hosting.

In that case - assuming that you have access to `.htaccess` - adding the following to `.htaccess` might work -

```
AddType text/html .html .htm .inc
```

Comment: Thanks GT. In the end I skirted round the problem but that information is really helpful!